# Fork process to execute executables through python/wsgi under Apache/Windows

Tags: python, django, apache, subprocess, mod-wsgi

I am currently working on a personal tiny Django site to manage my music and movie resources as an exercise.

The concrete environment:

- Python 2.7
- mod_wsgi 3.3
- Apache 2.2.22
- Windows XP

The problem I met is when I use `subprocess.Popen` to fork new process to open my movie in a certain player, the process will be forked in background, meaning that I can only see it in the Task Manager, but there is no visible Player Interface. So it is really strange because I can even hear the voice in the movie, but cannot see the picture.(I tried to open browsers and many other executables in this way, all running in background)

If I use the development server shipped with Django, this issue is gone. So I guess the issue is highly related to Apache or mod_wsgi ?

Any suggestions and advices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) and [STARTUPINFO.wShowWindow](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO.wShowWindow) parameters. You may want to use then when you start new process through `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: Thanks for your enlightening stuff !